# How to Install requests[security] in virtualenv in IntelliJ

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellij-idea, virtualenv

I'm using python 2.7.10 virtualenv when running python codes in IntelliJ. I need to install requests[security] package. However I'm not sure how to add that [security] option/config when installing requests package using the Package installer in File > Project Structure settings window.

Comment: When you open the 'Terminal' tool window (look for a button at the bottom), does the prompt say `(venv)` at the beginning?

Comment: @AlexHall no i don't see that

Comment: OK, so first we need to activate the virtualenv. What's the virtualenv folder called? It's probably `venv` or `virtualenv`.

Comment: @AlexHall got it, after activating the virtualenv in the 'Terminal' i did a pip install requests[security], it was successful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to install it by doing:

1. Activating the virtualenv in the 'Terminal' tool window:
   `source <virtualenv dir>/bin/activate`
2. Executing a `pip install requests[security]`